# How to write a good story-ID answer?

Tags: discussion, faq, story-identification

Our top tag is [story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification), with nearly 6000 questions and nearly 7000 answers, many of which are new users' first contributions to the site. Many of these new users need some guidance on how to answer a story-ID question well (include as many details as possible), and established users often need to leave comments along the lines of:

> Please add a summary or some details about this story so that we can tell how closely it matches the one described in the question.

The purpose of this meta post is to give us a single page to link these users to, for guidance on how to write a good story-ID answer and what to think of and include. It acts as a sequel to [this previous post](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) on how to write a good story-ID *question*.

### What advice would you offer on writing a good [story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification) answer?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As one of the site's top answerers of [story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification) questions (by volume), I tend to follow a very simple process when answering.

### Movie ID

- **Indicate the *name* of the film**
- **Indicate the *year* of the film** (if needed)
- **Link the name of the film to IMDB** (or another reliable source of information such as Rotten Tomatoes)
- **Include a brief synopsis of the film**, preferably one that mentions the points raised by the OP.
- **Include a youtube link to the film's trailer** (or the full film if one exists)
  and
- **If the OP has mentioned a specific scene and you can find a link to that scene (either a pic or a vid), add that as well.**

### Story ID

- **Indicate the name of the story**
- **Indicate the year of the story** (if needed)
- **Indicate the author of the story**
- **Link the story to an appropriate source.** For short-stories, I tend to use [ISFDB](https://www.isfdb.org/), for books I tend to use [goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/).
- **Add a synopsis of the story**, preferably one that mentions the points raised by the OP (or the full story if one exists in a copyright free format).
- **Mention any plot elements that *don't match the description given***.
- **Include the book's cover.**

Comment: I can't think of much to add here (although I did fix a typo). I sometimes also explain how I found an item, particularly if it required some esoteric searching. Also if some aspects of the question don't match, but do match to a similar work, I'll mention the other possible source in case the querent mixed them up.

Comment: Besides showing how the story *matches* the OP's description, it is important to note in detail every point in the description that *fails* to match because the OP has remembered incorrectly. We do this to make the Q & A more helpful to future users who are looking for the same story.

Comment: @user14111 - Hmm. I tend not to always bother with that, but I'll accept it as something we'd hope to see in an exemplary answer.

Comment: @Richard can you make this a community wiki?

Comment: @PeterPeter - I could, but since it's written from a personal perspective, I'd be loathe to do so without a solid justification. What changes do you feel it needs?

Comment: Adding quotes from the story to match key plot points that the OP has mentioned, For example see http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/122613/scientists-accidentally-breed-super-intelligent-mice/122677#122677 or any other answers by user14111

Comment: @PeterPeter - I'd have to disagree there. I find his answers to be massive overkill in a lot of cases. That one is an especially good example of that.

Comment: @Valorum these quotes are very helpful for users trying to find their story. For example, see the bounty reason on the [last story-id question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/113496/man-sheds-skin-like-a-snake-due-to-snake-bite-makes-face-masks/131390) I answered: "*Nice long answer, lots of details to show what matched, and link to the story I really wanted to find... I think it deserves a bounty.*"

Comment: @peterpeter - Which is fine, but I don't see it as an example of *best practice* to write then like that.

Comment: I don't see any reason to include the book's cover, except in those instances where the cover is described in the question. How do yoiu decide which cover to show, when the book has appeared in several editions with different covers, and the question does not point to any particular edition?

Comment: @user14111 - Because the imagery might help them to recall additional details about the story and thus confirm the rightness of the answer. If the book has had multiple covers, adding the one that's *most likely to be the right one* will likely assist them.

Comment: @user14111 - [This](http://www.goodreads.com/work/editions/1584694-the-clan-of-the-cave-bear) is a good example. Many differing cover styles but almost all around a common theme, with a similar pictures, a similar font and a large, prominently displayed author name. Even if you get the wrong edition, it's still liable to help.

Comment: I wonder if this answer could be split up into what we *expect* in a decent answer and what would be nice to make an *excellent* answer? I often drop comments to new ID answerers pointing to this post, but sometimes I feel bad because this makes it look as though we require an awful lot, whereas it can be fine not to include all the things you've listed: sometimes a Goodreads link and quoted synopsis is enough for a good answer.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - OP is asking for to write a *good* answer. Now, if they'd asked how to write an *adequate* answer, we might revisit.

Answer (score 4):

*Any* answer should include what and why. *What* is the answer? Can you identify the exact work? And *why* is that the answer? Does it match the description given?

## *What*

In the case of story IDs, the *what* should at least include the name of the work, the name of its creator(s), and the medium (was it a book, a short story, a (web) comic, a film, a television series, a game, and so on).

A rough indication of when it was first published, released, or broadcast is helpful as well, especially in the case where there are several works with that same title.

If it's a part of a series of franchise, naming that and placing it within that would help a lot too.

#### Written works

For a book or story, that means the title and the author, as well as a mention of what kind of work it is — series, book, novel(la), short story, or fan-fiction.

#### Film and television

For a film or television series, at least the title. Preferably the director and the main actors as well. Year of release or broadcast is a bit more important here than it is for books, since that helps narrow it down considerably, more so than with books that can often have several print runs and can be republished.

Indication of whether it was an adaptation or a remake can be very helpful as well — maybe you've seen the remake while the querent has seen the original, for instance.

#### Comics

For a comic, that should include the writer and the artist(s), the name of the series, and the number of the issue. Possibly the publisher as well.

#### Video Games

At least the title and the system it was released on. Preferably the company that released it too, as well as the year of release.

## *Why*

This is as important as *what*. The querent has described a number of elements that may or may not match. Either give a synopsis, or address them point by point.

Don't forget to address the points that do *not* match.

Linking to a source such as Wikipedia, the ISFDb for written works, Goodreads for books, the IMDb for films and television, Rotten Tomatoes for films, is very helpful, but only required if you quote from it.

## *How*

*How* is entirely optional, but a lot of people have searched extensively already. Telling them how you've found it might help them understand why they couldn't find it and may even help them searching for another title in the future.

---

### Linking to the work in question

While linking to the exact work can be very tempting, it may be in violation of copyright. A trailer on YouTube or any other video site is probably fine, especially if published there by the (presumed) copyright holder, such as the studio. Full films can be found as well, but should not be linked to unless you can be reasonably sure that it isn't in violation of copyright. Some short and even medium length films have been released on YouTube, by its creator(s).

The same goes for written works and comics. If published online by the author or artist, it's fine. Some writers publish online, some do that for old works that are no longer in print. Web comics are of course published online.

The Internet Archive has a very large collection of old magazines, in which stories may have been published before being published in book form. They're a large enough entity to assume they know what they're doing copyright-wise.

Do **not** link to torrents, rips, scans and such that are clearly in violation of copyright and often hosted on sites of dubious reputation and security as well.