# Please reopen this question

Tags: discussion, vote-to-reopen

The question

**[Series about a young man struggling to become king in middle ages setting](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/184328/series-about-a-young-man-struggling-to-become-king-in-middle-ages-setting)**

was closed because OP said he didn't remember any SF or Fantasy elements. Just because he didn't remember any, it doesn't mean there weren't any. As you can see from the comments, I think I have an answer. The novel has fantasy elements (dragon) after all; they're just downplayed.

Comment: related (you skipped straight to step 4): https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11667/what-should-be-done-with-on-hold-too-broad-questions-you-can-answer

Comment: If you think it's got fantasy elements, perhaps ask the OP in comments whether they can remember any fantasy elements from the books.

Comment: @JohnP Really, only step 2 was applicable, and I _did_ leave a comment, and OP did answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As [originally asked](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/184328/revisions) the question was off-topic and **rightly closed**. Since then, OP has added some additional information that brings it on-topic.

> *"Although I don't remember it having magic or fantasy elements, **it
>   definitely was either alternate history or just an non-Earth world.**
>   It's possible it was a low-magic setting."*

**The question should now be re-opened.**

Comment: I've re-opened it.

Comment: @null - [Tag:Status-Completed]