# Frequently Asked Questions

Tags: discussion, site-faq

Of course you've taken the [Tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour), read the entire [Help section](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help), and know our [Code of Conduct](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/conduct) by heart.

But have you read the [Frequently Asked Questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq) here on meta, that will help you make better use of the main site?
You can browse the questions tagged [faq](/questions/tagged/faq), but here are the most important ones, grouped by topic.

Comment: I hope a mod would be so nice to add [meta-tag:faq] and possibly [meta-tag:featured].

Comment: Please add (preferably community wiki) answers that define how we want to handle a specific topic on this Stack.

Comment: Highly related: [Proposals for a list of FAQ questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9298/31394)

Comment: @RandalThor highly related, but this one is meant to serve as the actual list itself.

Comment: Well, [here's one list](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq). Hmm, did I never create a meta post listing all [meta-tag:faq]-tagged questions by topic? Thought I had.

Comment: @Randal'Thor well, here it is (if you would be so kind to tag all listed questions [meta-tag:faq]).

Answer (score 4):

### Topicality

- [Is literary analysis on-topic?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11833/)
- [Are stories that only appear to contain fantastical elements on topic?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11587/)
- [Should we exclude religious texts, and which?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1053/)
- [Are works that aren't SF per se, but have occasional SFnal elements on-topic? (e.g. spy movies)](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/337/)
- [What is our actual policy on science questions?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7364/)

Also see [scope](/questions/tagged/scope)

Comment: Please add links to other questions that define our scope.

Answer (score 4):

### Identification

- [How to write a good story-ID answer?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9444/)
- [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/)
- [How to ask a good (fanfic) Story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11922/)
- [How to ask a good (anime) Story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11874/)
- [How to ask a good (video game) story-ID question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11995/)

Also see [story-identification](/questions/tagged/story-identification).

Comment: Please add links to other questions that define how we want to handle ID requests.

Comment: It's annoying me that I wrote fanfic with a capital F and the others without.

Comment: One must live with one's mistakes

Comment: @Valorum _someone_ fixed it, though.

Comment: There's always a good Samaritan on the road