# How to ask a good (fan fiction) Story-ID question?

Tags: discussion, story-identification

We seem to have a pretty regular number of story-ID questions specifically focused on finding half-remembered [fan-fiction](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fan-fiction) stories.

Our top tag is [story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification) with over 10,000 questions and we already have an excellent guide to help people answer them in "[How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)" that users can direct querents towards.

**What *additional* advice can we offer on writing a good story-identification question aimed at locating a fanfic story?**

Answer (score 15):

On top of Valorum's list, it is also helpful to describe the **relationship between the fic and the original:**

- **Tone and narrative voice** - Is the fic written in the same overall style?  For example, *A Song of Ice and Fire* is known for killing off characters, while *Wall-E* is not.  Does the fic observe similar practices to the original in this and other ways?
- **Genre** - Did Harry Potter get abducted by aliens with ray guns?  Did the *Enterprise* land on a planet of wizards with pointy hats?
- **Setting** - Is the fic [set](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/HighSchoolAU) in a [high school](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_school_(North_America)) or some other environment that doesn't look like the original?
- **Characters** - Is a good character evil, or *vice-versa?*  Did someone get aged up or down dramatically?  Were any new characters introduced?
- **Multiple canonicity** - Some stories ("crossovers") mix two or more different fictional universes.  There are actually multiple ways of doing that:

  - Integrate the universes together, forming a new whole (e.g. Captain Han Solo of the *USS Enterprise* helps Jedi Padawan Wesley Crusher defeat the evil Romulan empire after the latter destroys Betazed with their Death Star).
  - Keep the universes initially separate, but put them in the same physical space (e.g. the *Enterprise*, with no human crewmembers and no knowledge of Earth, lands on a planet which [SG-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stargate_SG-1) is exploring).
  - Have characters from one universe explicitly cross over to the other (e.g. the TARDIS lands in the middle of any non-*Doctor Who* universe, with the Doctor giving some technobabble about how far away they've traveled or similar).
- **Plot** - Did events happen differently?  Did Greedo shoot and kill Han in Mos Eisley, and derail the entire story?
- **Any other striking differences or similarities** between the fic and the original.

Obviously, it is also important to mention **the original which it was based on.** While this may seem trivial, a story about Romulans may look very different if it is based on the [*Rihannsu*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rihannsu) novels than if it is based on regular *Star Trek* canon (i.e. the TV shows and movies), so if the former are in play, you should mention them explicitly.

Answer (score 14):

In addition to the elements we've already discussed in [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question), fanfic-specific elements that the poster could identify include:

- **The site that you viewed it on, specifically whether it was [fanfiction.net](http://www.fanfiction.net), [Archive of Our Own](https://archiveofourown.org/) (Ao3) or something else.**
- **Whether the story had any adult or pornographic content.**
- **Any part or portion of the author's name**
- **Whether you've seen it discussed anywhere as a "fic you have to read"**
- **What *tags* the story had (MPreg, Dramione, etc) when it was posted.**
- **Who the characters were in the story and what their ages were at the time of telling.**
- **What *pairings* occurred in the story along with an explanation of any special jargon used (e.g "Dramione" = "Draco/Hermione pairing")**
- **Any *specific words or unusual/unique phrases* that were used in the story.**

Bear in mind that a single line description will probably fit multiple stories ("*fanfic where Hermione fell in love with the troll in the bathroom*" = hundreds of matches). **Remember that the more detail you can give us, the more likely it is that we can narrow it down to a single story.**

Comment: *"fanfic where Hermione fell in love with the troll" = hundreds* Ewwww.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - Hundreds of times of ewwww

Comment: @Randal'Thor Ron is a bit of a troll...

Comment: @Randal'Thor shouldn't this be tagged [meta-tag:faq]?

Answer (score 3):

An additional one, which is oft overlooked, is narrative voice/format. Is it written in first person? Third person? Third person omniscient? Is it written in script format (a more common choice a decade or two ago)? Because identifying fanfic is often highly dependent on personal experience, this becomes more important.